# Best practice for storing simple variables like 'total rows' in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

In my symfony2 application I need to display some totals at the top of all pages, ie "Already 200,154,555 users registered".

I don't want to run the query to come up with that count on every page load. The solution I've come up with is to create a "variable" entity that would have two columns, name and value. Then I would set up a console command that runs on cron which would update these variable entities (eg "totalPeople") with a query that counted all the rows of people, etc.

This feels a little heavy handed... Is there a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set global parameters and add a service to rewrite them. Then call the service from your Command.

Or directly set up a service to read/write a file (as a json array for example).

Or set up a option table with a row storing the data. It's not going to be a resource intensive query that way.

Here is what I'm using to store RSS feeds (after I parsed them)

```
  public function checkCache($data=array(), $path = '')
  {
    foreach ($data as $service => $feed)
    {
      $service = strtolower($service);
      $service =  str_replace(' ', '-', $service);
      $path = $path.'web/bundles/citation/cache/rss/' . $service . '.cache';
      if ((!file_exists($path) || time() - filemtime($path) > 900) && $cache = fopen($path, 'w'))
      {

        $rss_contents = $this->getFeed($feed); //fetch feed content & returns array 
        fwrite($cache, serialize($rss_contents));
        fclose($cache);
        return $rss_contents;
      }
      else
      {

        $cache = fopen($path, 'r');
        return unserialize(file_get_contents($path));
        fclose($cache);

      }
    }
  }
```

You can implement that on your backend for example so every time an admin logs it'll check for cache and refresh only if it's too old. Although I'm quite fond of the 4AM cron job solution too.

Comment: Thanks these all sound like great options. Option 1 sounds very nice, would you just use fread fwrite to update the value of the variable in  a parameters.yml file? That seems a little sketchy. Option 3 sounds close to what I was originally thinking, but my understanding is that I should be bending my thinking around Doctrine's ORM and should only be saving objects to the DB, not setting up just an option table. But it sure does sound simple so I may just go with it.

Comment: Very cool. Thanks for the example. I'll do something like this-

Comment: You'd have to set up your own params.yml and make a service that uses the YAML component Yaml::dump, Yaml::parse methods to read and edit the .yml. I don't think it's the way to go nor the easier for what you want to do

Comment: For option 3 what I meant was you can create an Option entity then just find it by id and edit it when you need. Just delete this line @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") on the id property, add the setId() method and set it to whatever in your form.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pagination feature of doctrine (if you use doctrine). That will leverage the "limit" part of your queries (even with joins) and will give you a total count of rows (via a count query).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not sure this solves my problem. I have no issue getting the total row count...the issue is that I need these stats to show up on every page, and the queries needed to get the row totals take a few seconds total to execute (i already have millions of rows). Therefore, I need to cache that value somehow, and I'm not sure what the best approach to doing so is.